# Memory Problems with Ubuntu 22.04 after upgrading packages

Tags: apt, upgrade, 22.04, ram

I upgraded (just packages via apt update && apt upgrade) my ubuntu 22.04 system this morning.
Since then I have problems with the memory. I have 24 GB RAM installed in my HP Notebook. Ubuntu just detects 2,3 GB. It results in many oom Kills. I can't really work anymore with my Notebook.

```
~$ sudo lshw pc                       
    Beschreibung: Notebook
    Produkt: HP ProBook 455 G7 (1B7V7ES#ABD)
    Hersteller: HP
    Seriennummer: XXXXXXXXX
    Breite: 64 bits
    Fähigkeiten: smbios-3.1.1 dmi-3.1.1 smp vsyscall32
    Konfiguration:    *-core
       Beschreibung: Hauptplatine
       Produkt: 8730
       Hersteller: HP
       Physische ID: 0
       Version: KBC Version 13.19.00
       Seriennummer: XXXXXXXX
     *-memory
          Beschreibung: Systemspeicher
          Physische ID: 1
          Steckplatz: Systemplatine oder Hauptplatine
          Größe: 24GiB
        *-bank:0
             Beschreibung: SODIMM DDR4 Synchron Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0,3 ns)
             Produkt: M471A2K43DB1-CWE
             Hersteller: Samsung
             Physische ID: 0
             Seriennummer: 38CB4239
             Steckplatz: Bottom-Slot 1(left)
             Größe: 16GiB
             Breite: 64 bits
             Takt: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
        *-bank:1
             Beschreibung: SODIMM DDR4 Synchron Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0,3 ns)
             Produkt: M471A1K43DB1-CWE
             Hersteller: Samsung
             Physische ID: 1
             Seriennummer: 37B162BE
             Steckplatz: Bottom-Slot 2(right)
             Größe: 8GiB
             Breite: 64 bits
             Takt: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
```

Output of `free -hm`:

```
              gesamt       benutzt     frei        gemns.    Puffer/Cache verfügbar 
Speicher:      2,3Gi       1,9Gi       149Mi        22Mi        251Mi       169Mi 
Auslager:      2,0Gi       997Mi       1,0Gi
```

Does anyone have the same problems?

A upgrade to 22.10 doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You should probably run a memory test - or try to switch to some other memory entirely, if it's possible (to test).

Comment: I already made a bios mem test and it passed. Booting a Fedora Live Linux shows the right mem of 24 GB. It looks like there is something wrong with my ubuntu installation.

Comment: Bios Update solved the problem for me.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem isn't solved. It happens now sporadically. Looks like I have to reinstall OS on my notebook.